# sub query returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql

I have to write a query which returns the price of books greater than the average price for books of similar type. So, I did this using the below query:

```
select title
from titles
where price >
(
   select avg(price)
   from titles
   group by type
)
```

However it throws this error:

```
subquery returned more than 1 value
```

It is understandable that > cannot be used for a list of values. But I wanted to know the way I can solve this. Please let me know the query I need to use. The DB is pubs

```
titles table:

title_id , title, type, price, advance, notes, sales
```

so I need to get the title with price > average (price) of similar types

Comment: If you have more than one "type" in your "titles" table, the group by will cause multiple rows.  If you just want an average price across the whole table, remove the "group by" in your subquery.

Comment: What flavor of sql are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have more than one type, so each type is returning an average.

You can look into the [SOME|ANY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064.aspx) or [ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx) operators to look at the list of items

If you were looking for the titles whose prices are higher than all of the average types, An example of this would be:

```
SELECT title
FROM titles
WHERE price > ALL
(
   SELECT AVG(price)
   FROM titles
   GROUP BY type
)
```

You could similarly change `ALL` to `SOME` or `ANY` to suit your needs.

Answer (score 6):

The key is to use the type from the main query to filter the type in the subquery.

```
SELECT t.title 
    FROM titles t 
    WHERE t.price > (SELECT AVG(t2.price) 
                         FROM titles t2
                         WHERE t2.type = t.type)
```

Comment: Probably what the OP wants more than my answer, +1.

Comment: I agree with @AdamWenger.  I could update my answer but it would reflect exactly what you have here.  +1

Answer (score 1):

```
select title 
from titles 
where price > 
(select avg(price) from titles)
```

The above query assumes that you want the average of all title prices to compare against.  This will return a scalar value and allow your query to succeed.

Comment: but it should get the avg of similar types and then check with the price column

Comment: @Nishanth then you need to have a filter in your subquery so that it only returns a single value.  If you give me more information about the `titles` table I can write it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link types from subquery and main query, example:

```
select
   a.title
from
   titles a
where
   a.price > ( select avg(b.price) from titles b where a.type = b.type group by b.type)
```

Comment: You don't need the group by in your subquery

Comment: It's a fact, my mistake. Thanks for.